# Laravel 8 One to One messaging, any suggestions?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, web-applications, message

Hello I would like to implement a real-time one to one messaging system between the users of my application. The estimated amount of users is 10000. I don't want to use web sockets or any other similar solution. I also use livewire for other features. I though of creating this using ajax polling and refresh the messages every 10 seconds but I assume that this way would not be efficient and may slow down my application's performance.

Do you have any suggestions on how can I achieve a real-time one to one messaging system?

Comment: websocket is the best thing you can do

Comment: You should use websockets as @KamleshPaul suggested. Alternatively you can use Pusher/Ably with Laravel Echo. Here's the [pusher link](https://pusher.com/tutorials/chat-laravel/). Hope it helps

Comment: @HassanMalik push also websocket hosted on pusher server :D

Comment: @KamleshPaul I know, I suggested this as pusher reduces the pain of managing sockets from your end.

Comment: Thanks guys appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Laravel Websockets](https://beyondco.de/docs/laravel-websockets/getting-started/introduction) is your friend ;)

Comment: Thanks @knubbe it works great, just what I needed.